# What is the name of the Tabs widget in the devtools inspect panel?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, devtools, inspect

What is the name of the **tabs widget** marked with a red circle in the image?
Anyone who does not recognize this is a **devtools inspect panel**, thanks!

[image: tabs widget marked with a red circle]

If there is no direct access to the above tabs widget, how do you view the HTML code and stylesheet of the panel?